# Commits missing after incomplete "git svn dcommit"

Tags: git-svn, commit

I'm missing a few important commits after my computer lost power in the middle of a "git svn dcommit" operation, and I'm unsure of how to get them back. "git log" doesn't show the commits, any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Git keeps track of everything you do to the repository in the [reflog](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html). You can use `git reflog` to view recent commits, and resurrect them from there.

I found a blog entry called [git reflog: no commits left behind](http://gitfu.wordpress.com/2008/04/06/git-reflog-no-commits-left-behind/) which describes what to do to recover these commits.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to do a "git log" and/or "git branch -v" before doing anything that might change branches, like "git svn dcommit". You can always scroll back the console and copy/paste the commit IDs in case they get messed up.